# Curl sept_opt and sept_opt_array undefined function despite php curl extension

Tags: php, apache, stripe-payments, php-curl

I have problems to use curl in order to do some stripe payments.I installed the php curl extension with using the absolute path in ext folder but sept_opt is still undefined but curl_init() seems ok.

[image: screenshot php info extension]

Install extension php, install curl.exe, system variables

print_r(curl_getinfo($ch)); :

> Array ( [url] => [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0
>   [request_size] => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>   [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 0
>   [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0
>   [size_download] => 0 [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0
>   [download_content_length] => -1 [upload_content_length] => -1
>   [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] =>
>   [primary_ip] => [certinfo] => Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip]
>   => [local_port] => 0 [http_version] => 0 [protocol] => 0 [ssl_verifyresult] => 0 [scheme] => [appconnect_time_us] => 0
>   [connect_time_us] => 0 [namelookup_time_us] => 0 [pretransfer_time_us]
>   => 0 [redirect_time_us] => 0 [starttransfer_time_us] => 0 [total_time_us] => 0 )

```
if (!function_exists('curl_setopt_array')) {
    function curl_setopt_array(&$ch, $curl_options)
    {
        foreach ($curl_options as $option => $value) {
            if (!curl_setopt($ch, $option, $value)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
 }
      $ch = curl_init();
      print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
      $url="http://api.stripe.com/v1/".$endpoint;
      curl_septopt($ch, CURL_OPT_URL, $url);
      curl_septopt($ch,  CURL_OPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_septopt($ch,  CURL_OPT_USERPWD, $this->api_key ) ;
      curl_septopt($ch,  CURL_HTTP_AUTH , CURL_AUTH_BASIC);
      curl_septopt($ch,  CURL_OPTIONS_POSTFIELDS , 'http_build_query('.$data.')');
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_septopt()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\venifruit\libs\stripe.php:29 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\venifruit\modules\espace-achat-primeur\stripe-creer-paiement.php(17):
>   Stripe->api('customers', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\venifruit\index.php(187):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\venifruit\libs\stripe.php on line 29

Comment: you should be using the SSL protected endpoint - ie: `https` so you need to add curl options for dealing with SSL connections. That said, `curl_septopt` should be `curl_setopt`

Comment: ok so tired i'm working on week end i  think i did the mistake. i'll try

Comment: I think it's ok i have other errors but the function is recognized because it's parameters errors. I need rest now i think. I didnt' even notice the name error. So sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The method is called `curl_setopt();` and **not** `curl_septopt();`.

```
      $ch = curl_init();
      print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
      $url="http://api.stripe.com/v1/".$endpoint;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURL_OPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURL_OPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURL_OPT_USERPWD, $this->api_key) ;
      curl_setopt($ch, CURL_HTTP_AUTH , CURL_AUTH_BASIC);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Also, there is no need to encode the Postfields. When passed as Array, it will encode it. Read the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use ssl connections the easier is that way
take this class on github and install to the root of server : [Stripe class on github](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/releases)

And use this easy code :

```
 require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php'); // Don't forget this line link to the right  library

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_votre-clé-api-stripe-secrete-test");

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];
  $email  = $_POST['stripeEmail'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'source'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 500,
      'currency' => 'eur',
      'description' => 'Discover France Guide by Erasmus of Paris',
      'receipt_email' => $email  
  ));

  echo '<h1>Payment accepted!</h1>';
```